# formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments error

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I have been given a data to check if the features in the dataset of a student can affect their overall performance. For this task, I am checking if the travel time to school can affect a students overall grade. I am trying to create a graph but I have an error.
This is the code for graph:

```
plot(data, type="1", xlab="G3", ylab="traveltime",
     main="Plot to show student travel time", col="red")
# Error in plot.default(...) : 
#   formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I am not sure how to fix the error.

Comment: Note, that there is no `type='1'`, you probably meant `type='l'`.

Answer (score 1):

You're obviously attempting to plot a data frame.

```
plot(Loblolly, type="l")
# Error in plot.default(...) : 
#   formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

When you call `plot` on a `"data.frame"`, the method `plot.data.frame` is dispatched. If `ncol(x) > 2`, this method calls the `pairs` function which already has `type="n"` argument in line 96 and gets another one passed through the ellipse `...`.

```
pairs(Loblolly, type="l")
# Error in plot.default(...) : 
#   formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

So, use `pairs` directly, and either avoid the `type='l'` argument.

```
pairs(Loblolly)
```

[image]

Or use a custom `panel.*` function, e.g. on the diagonal.

```
panel.lines <- function(x, ...) {
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr=c(0, 1, 0, 1), new=TRUE)
  plot(x, type='l')
}

pairs(Loblolly, diag.panel=panel.lines)
```

[image]